# Cannot read property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dojo

Im using the CheckedMultiSelect of dojo in this way,

```
var MyCheckedMultiSelect = declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {

         startup: function() {
             this.inherited(arguments);
             setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function() {
              this.dropDownButton.set("label", "User Preferences");
             }));
         }v
 var select =   new MyCheckedMultiSelect({
        dropDown: true,
        label: "Preferences",
        multiple: true,
        name: 'state',
        invalidMessage: 'ERROR',
        onChange: getValues,
        required: true
    }, "stateSelect");
    form = new Form({
    style: 'display:inline'
    }, 'formPref');
    select.startup();

select._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText = 'User Preferences';
```

I wanted to override the message "0 item(s) selected" of this widget which comes by default to some other message like "User Preferences".. So im using this 
select._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText = 'User Preferences';

But my page doesnot loads at all for the first time , it hangs with the following error
"Cannot read property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined".. Provide some pointers to debug this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `CheckedMultiSelect` refers to `dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect`
If yes, try something like this:

```
var MyCheckedMultiSelect = declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {
     postMixInProperties: function() {
          this.inherited(arguments);
          this._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText = 'User Preferences';
     }
     startup: function() {
         this.inherited(arguments);
         setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function() {
          this.dropDownButton.set("label", "User Preferences");
         }));
     }
 });
```

the override is moved inside your `MyCheckedMultiSelect` widget.

This is the original `postMixInProperties` method of `CheckedMultiSelect` :

```
postMixInProperties: function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this._nlsResources = i18n.getLocalization("dojox.form", "CheckedMultiSelect", this.lang);
    if(this.invalidMessage == "$_unset_$"){ this.invalidMessage = this._nlsResources.invalidMessage; }
},
```

original `postMixInProperties` will run first, then the `postMixInProperties` of your custom widget will override the value of `this._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText`

See the snippet:

```js
require(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(declare, CheckedMultiSelect) {
  
  var MyCheckedMultiSelect = declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {
     postMixInProperties: function() {
       this.inherited(arguments);
       this._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText = 'This is multiSelectLabelText';
     },
     startup: function() {
       this.inherited(arguments);
       this.dropDownButton.set("label", "This is dropDownButton label");
     }
  });

  
  var x = new MyCheckedMultiSelect({
    dropDown: true,
    label: "This is MyCheckedMultiSelect label",
    multiple: true,
    name: 'state',
    invalidMessage: 'ERROR',
    onChange: function() {},
    required: true,
    options: [
      { value: 'option1', label: 'label option 1' },
      { value: 'option2', label: 'label option 2' },
      { value: 'option3', label: 'label option 3' }
    ]
  
  });
  x.placeAt(document.getElementById('test'));
  x.startup();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojox/form/resources/CheckedMultiSelect.css">


<div id="test" class="tundra">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the above code im getting " TypeError: Unable to get property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined or null reference in domReady callback TypeError: Unable to get property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined or null reference" this error

Comment: That is not very clear... There is no domReady in the code above. So you have to give more details or update the question

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined

Im getting this error

Comment: this.inherited(arguments);  is coming as undefined and label is not getting changed

Comment: this.inherited(arguments) Unable to get property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined or null reference
im  getting this error in internet Explorer 11

Comment: Can you update the question with more code ? I've added a snippet to the answer and it works. There is no error

Comment: I have used same snippet, for the first time it works fine..
If i refresh the same page again, im getting 


TypeError: Unable to set property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined or null reference in domReady callback TypeError: Unable to set property 'multiSelectLabelText' of undefined or null reference



at postMixInProperties (https://135.250.203.91:8443/oms1350/web/eqm/js/comet.js:169:8)--->this is my file where i have included the snippet..



at create (https://135.250.203.91:8443/oms1350/web/eqm/dojoroot/dijit/_WidgetBase.js:63:1)